# How to type onChange in React-Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need help

How can I typed onChange which depends on isMulti. How to write correct dependense condtition?

```
onChange?(
  option: SelectProps<T>.isMulti extends true ? MultiValue<T> : SingleValue<T>,
): void
```

```
export interface SelectProps<T> {
    options?: T[]
    value: T | T[] | null | undefined
    isDisabled?: boolean
    placeholder?: string
    titleByKey?: string
    isSearchable?: boolean
    isClearable?: boolean
    isCreatable?: boolean
    isMulti?: boolean
    filterByLabel?: boolean
    name?: string
    inputValue?: string
    onCloseResetsInput?: boolean
    onBlurResetsInput?: boolean
    formatCreateLabel?: (inputValue: string) => string
    onBlur?: FocusEventHandler
    getOptionLabel?(option: T): string | number | null | undefined
    getOptionValue?(option: T): string | number | boolean | null | undefined
    onChange?(
        option: SelectProps<T>.isMulti extends true ? MultiValue<T> : SingleValue<T>,
    ): void
    onInputChange?(newValue: string, actionMeta: InputActionMeta): void
    onInputKeyDown?(e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>): void
    hasError?: boolean
    menuIsOpen?: boolean
    maxMenuHeight?: number
    menuPlacement?: string
    hideSelectedOptions?: boolean
    isLoading?: boolean
}
```

I don't now how to do it )
How can I typed onChange which depends on isMulti. How to write correct dependense condtition?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic type for the SelectProps interface that extends the isMulti property to define the type of value passed to the onChange method. Here's how you can modify the SelectProps interface and the onChange definition:

```
type MultiValue<T> = T[];
type SingleValue<T> = T | null | undefined;

export interface SelectProps<T, Multi extends boolean> {
    // ... other properties
    isMulti?: Multi
    onChange?: (
        option: Multi extends true ? MultiValue<T> : SingleValue<T>,
    ) => void
    // ... other properties
}
```

Now, when you use the SelectProps interface, you need to provide both the T and Multi types, which will determine the type of value passed to the onChange method:

```
interface MyOption {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}

const MyMultiSelect: React.FC<SelectProps<MyOption, true>> = (props) => {
    // ...
};

const MySingleSelect: React.FC<SelectProps<MyOption, false>> = (props) => {
    // ...
};
```

By providing the second type argument as true or false, you will get the correct type for the onChange method based on whether the select component is a multi-select or a single-select.